# Displaying C++ compilation errors in the VS 2013 editor

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with the Productivity Power Tools extension installed.

Can I set things up so that C++ compilation errors are marked in the editor (using squiggly underlines, scrollbar markers, etc.), in addition to being reported in the Error List?

Currently, only IntelliSense errors are displayed in the editor.

I have tried going to the "Scroll Bar" options and ensuring that "Show errors" is checked, but that didn't help anything.

Comment: C++ does not lend itself well to background compilation.  IntelliSense errors are a reasonable alternative, stepping through the Error List after building works.  Hovering the mouse over the red squiggles displays a tooltip with the error message.  That's as far as you can hope it to go.

Comment: I am not referring to background compilation. I am referring to the errors that result from a foreground, normal, compilation.

Comment: It isn't very clear to me why the Error List window isn't effective for you.

Comment: Well, I get two types of errors. First, IntelliSense errors, which are detected by VS as I type, and these are marked in the editor just fine. Second, I have the errors that result from compilation (which, usually, are in greater numbers and more comprehensive than what IntelliSense can detect on the fly). These are displayed in the Error List, but are not marked in the editor.

Comment: Just to clarify: the ErrorList works fine (I never said otherwise). It's the marking of those errors in the editor I'm asking about.

Comment: A C++ compiler only generates a line number to provide context for the error.  Not much any IDE could do with that beyond making the line visible.  So that's all it does.

Comment: Well, one thing that does comes to mind that an IDE could do with just a line number is mark the respective line with a red dot. Check out my question for other ideas ;)

Comment: You are talking to the wrong people about this, we don't work for Microsoft in the MSVC++ team.  You can post suggestions at the [VS uservoice site](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio).  Best to flesh this out a bit, they are not likely to be very thrilled about a "red dot" suggestion.

Comment: I'm not making a feature request, I'm asking if this is possible. If your answer is "no", then please formulate that as an answer and let's give others the chance to chip in as well. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be addressed to the MS tools team

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I disagree (see my previous comment as well).

Comment: I started this meta question regarding the validity of this question's closure: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257900/why-has-my-question-been-put-on-hold

Comment: I opened a feature request for this: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5996489-mark-c-compilation-errors-in-the-source-code-edi

Comment: You know that if you double-click an error in the error list, it will take you to the line in question, right?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: You beat me to it by seconds.

Comment: @HansPassant: "A C++ compiler only generates a line number to provide context for the error." – I don't buy this. There's nothing in the C++ spec that forces this, and there are compilers which provide rich interaction between the IDE and the compiler. In fact, this was a specific design goal in clang, and is used to great effect in Xcode. It's kind of stunning actually, that msvc *doesn't* do this, considering that Microsoft is on the forefront of C++ IDE technology.

Comment: Ought to be a little obvious why, the C++ compiler doesn't see the actual source code.  The preprocessor messes it up.  Sure, clang did something about it because everybody hates this, its primary reason for being.  Always nice when you can start from scratch and don't have to keep existing customers happy.  So there, trolling you right back :)

Comment: @HansPassant I guess Jörg's point is that in an integrated environment there is nothing preventing the pre-processor from working with the compiler IDE to enable this kind of error reporting. A simple line number translation option for the preprocessor would be reasonably simple enough to implement (and backwards compatible).

Comment: That already exists.  The columns are the problem.

Comment: Then it means at least line markers should be reasonably straightforward to implement. Hopefully others will think this is useful too, and MS will look at my feature request (thanks for the link, btw).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 doesn't have this option. 
I opened a [feature request](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5996489-mark-c-compilation-errors-in-the-source-code-edi) on the MS website.